# Ajax jQuery redirect like GitHub or Neowin

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, github, href

I'm building a website using pure HTML tags. When I use an hyperlink tag like `<a href="http://mydomain/xx">xx</a>` I want to redirect to `<a href="http://mydomain/yy">yy</a>`. It works, but I want a smooth Ajax redirect like those used in GitHub.

In `https://github.com/jquery/plugins.jquery.com`, if you click any of those links below `plugins.jquery.com`, you can see a smooth Ajax redirect.

In Neowin you can see those smooth redirects if you click on any of those page buttons at the bottom.

How can I do a Ajax redirect from this little HTML page using jQuery or something similar?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Page 1</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="page2">Page 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

From the code above I want the **a href** to be Ajax redirected. I don't care about fancy effects for now, but I want that smoothness.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a specialized function especially on GitHub. You will have to do several things:

1. Check for `click` event on every link on the page or in a certain container (see http://api.jquery.com/on/)
2. Then you do the real AJAX request (see http://api.jquery.com/get/)
3. You will get the whole HTML page as a response, which you can filter and only update the parts of the page that actually change - or if you want to replace the whole page, do so (see http://api.jquery.com/html/)

If you can elaborate a bit more on what you tried so far, we can help you much better.

Comment: OK, so you want to replace the whole page. Then you can proceed as I described. Watch for link clicks, get the href, do an AJAX GET request and replace the contents of your page. Just try it out, it's not really hard. If you have any further questions, I can edit my answer.

Comment: After reading your jquery links about ON, GET and HTML I think is not going to work in the way I want.   I'm looking for a redirect but with the html tags in there in order to be readable by search engines.